# Making a two dimensional array at run time using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have been trying to allocate a 2 dimensional array at run time using `malloc` by using the concept of pointers to pointers. This code doesn't show any compilation error but gives a runtime error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int ** alpha(void)
{
    int **x;

    x=(int **)malloc(3*sizeof(int *));

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    x[0]=(int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            x[i][j]=i+j;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int **p;

    p=alpha();

    printf("%d",p[1][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a difference in C between a two-dimensional array and an array-of-arrays, btw. This is the latter.

Comment: And the run time error is..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the runtime error is because you allocate memory just for `x[0]`.So, change

```
x[0]=(int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

to

```
x[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

and [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1):

In

```
x[0]=(int *)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

you ended up allocating memory for only index `0` three times. use `i`.

After you're done using , don't forget to `free()` the allocated memory. Otherwise, it'll result in a *memory leak*.

Also, no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`/`calloc()`.